# How to add CP-1252 to CentOS

Tags: windows, linux, centos, character-encoding, utf-8

We are processing files that our clients generated on their local Windows machines which use the CP-1252 character set. Occasionally, while processing one of these files in our backend (running on CentOS), we get runtime errors (it's a Java backend, so `RuntimeExceptions`). If we remote in to the server and rename the file (using UTF-8) and re-run it, the file processes perfectly fine.

Is there any way to "add" CP-1252 to CentOS's available character sets so that this stops happening?

Comment: Can you post the Java run-time exception that you receive?  And call stack?  Is the issue that there is a CP-1252 character in the file name that is being processed by a Java program?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn - I will need a few hours before I can get access to the appropriate logs to get the exact stacktrace, but yes, you nailed it. It happens when there is a CP-1252 character in the file name and the system chokes. Simply SSHing in to the server, renaming it and re-processing the file fixes it, but is a sub-optimal (manual!) solution.

Comment: Do you have any control over the code that creates that file that is processed by your Java back-end or over the source code to the Java application that processes the file?

Comment: Only the backend but not the (client-side) file generator. But the Java backend is 100% under our control.

Comment: How come you can't fix the Java program to read the data as bytes and then pass it through a decoder?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this bug report from Oracle on the behavior of Java [bug_id=4733494](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4733494) related to the "default locale".  According to this bug report (actually Sun/Oracle says that this behavior is really not a bug but just how Java was designed), from Sun/Oracle:

> In versions of the JDK prior to 1.4, we always forced the "C" locale
> to the ISO8859-1 character set.  In releases 1.4 and later, we support
> the "C" locale which requires restriction to 7-bit ASCII.

The recommendation is to set environment variable `LC_ALL` to `en_US.ISO8859-1` or whatever the appropriate locale for the system should be `es_ES.ISO-8859-1`, etc.

Adding:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
```

To the command file that runs your Java back-end should resolve the problem.

This is also documented in SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663709/how-to-fix-java-when-if-refused-to-open-a-file-with-special-charater-in-filename

Comment: Thanks @HeatfanJohn (+1) - quick followup: what's this "C" locale? I've never heard of it before or seen it referenced anywhere. What purpose does it serve? Thanks again!

Comment: @zharvey I didn't know what that was either.  From this http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_19.html#SEC324 web page it appears to be a legacy GNU C locale.

Comment: @zharvey if you run `locale` from a command prompt on your Linux system, what is output?

Comment: The "C" locale does no (i.e. bitwise) collation, no number or currency formatting, and primitive date and time formatting, and does not translate the native strings used in an application.